# center one image, and right align another, in the same line

Tags: css, skeleton-css-boilerplate

In the code below, I want to center `logo.jpg` across the entire page, and right align `shopping_cart.jpg` in the same line. The problem with the current set up is that the image on the right causes the the image in the center to shift slightly to the left.

I'm using Skeleton CSS Boilerplate, and  I don't want to put these 2 images in different divs because then in order to be responsive in mobile view, the center-aligned image will appear on top, and the right-aligned image will appear below it (I want them to continue to appear in one line in mobile view).

```
<div class="container" style="text-align:center">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">

            <img width="50%" src="images/logo.jpg">

            <img width="5%" src="images/shopping_cart.jpg" style="float:right">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, is there some way to center `logo.jpg` across the entire page, and right align `shopping_cart.jpg` in the same line, such that `logo.jpg` doesn't shift slightly to the left because of the presence of `shopping_cart.jpg`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of float right, try

```
position: absolute; and right: 0;
```

and on .column :

```
position: relative;
```

Comment: Fantastic, that worked. Will mark it correct when it lets me.

Answer (score 1):

i think this will do the trick. Copy and paste :)

CSS:

```
.column {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}

.column img:nth-of-type(1) {
position: absolute;
top:0;
left: 50%;
}

.column img:nth-of-type(2) {
position: absolute;
top:0;
right: 0;
 }
```